# Multiple Communication Channels (Bluetooth PAN and LTE) per App

Tags: android, bluetooth, lego-mindstorms

I want to write an Android App which should connect to a Lego Mindstorms EV3 via Bluetooth PAN (Android == Client, Lego == Server). This would render my device without Internet.

Since I need my App to be connected to the Internet I'm looking for a possibility to control the communication channels which the app uses (Bluetooth PAN (thus rendering the device without Internet) to communicate with the LEGO AND LTE).

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

With [ev3dev](http://ev3dev.org), you can setup the EV3 so that it is a "server" using the Bluetooth PAN profile. To do this you just enable "tethering" via Bluetooth on the EV3. Then the Android device will be able to connect to the EV3 as a client.

However, I don't know enough about Android networking to know if it is capable of using more than one network at a time.

Or, if your Android is capable of tethering via Bluetooth, you can share your Android's Internet connection (presumably LTE) to the EV3 like [this](http://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/connecting-to-the-internet-via-bluetooth/?os=Android). Then the Android will still be connected to the Internet and there will be a network connection between the EV3 and the Android (and the EV3 will be connected to the Internet as well).

Comment: I'm currently using LEJOS which is like ev3dev a third party firmware. I'm already tethered to the EV3 but this tethering means, that I sacrifice the internetconnection of my Android Device since the EV3 is Master (without Internet) and the Android Device is Client.

Comment: You should be able to setup leJOS like the last part of my answer. Or if you can't figure it out on leJOS, give ev3dev a try.